# Monte Carlo integration for Bayesian parameter estimation

Tags: bayesian, monte-carlo, posterior, credible-interval, numerical-integration

I want to determine the credible interval of a quantity $\theta_1$. I want to make this estimate using observed data by assuming a certain model which depends on $\theta_1$ as well as about n=15 nuisance parameters $\theta_2, \ldots, \theta_n$.

I have a likelihood function $\mathcal L(x|\boldsymbol\theta)$ where $x$ are my observations which I can calculate for any $\boldsymbol \theta$.

I also have priors $\pi(\boldsymbol \theta)$ which I can similarly calculate for any $\boldsymbol \theta$.

My plan is as follows.

1. Draw a large number of samples of $\boldsymbol \theta$ from a uniform random distribution. (*Monte Carlo step*)
2. Calculate the posterior $p = \mathcal{L}(x|\theta)\cdot\pi(\theta)$ for each sample. (*Bayes step*)
3. Calculate the weighted mean and standard deviation of $\theta_1$, where the weights are $p$. (*Integration step*)

Does this make sense? If not, can someone please point me in the right direction?  If so, is there a way to estimate how many samples I will need?

(In practice I think I will actually use quasi-Monte Carlo sampling by making use of Sobol numbers, but I think this detail is not important for the question.)

I know how to solve this problem using MCMC, but my likelihood function is very expensive to calculate and so I prefer a simpler way to make this estimate.

Comment: The uniform distribution only makes sense as an importance function if the support of the posterior is _inside_ the support of the uniform distribution.

Comment: Simulating from an unrelated importance distribution like the Uniform is quite likely to be more costly than MCMC. Even quasi-Monte Carlo is an issue when the posterior is well-concentrated.